# How to redirect a get request to another post request in express js?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to redirect a get request to another server post. i don't know how to do that. the following is my code.

**server 1: get method**

```
app.get('/sampleTestApp', function (req, res) {
   body={uid:'test'}
   // Want to redirect here to server 2 'login/callback' url with body object
}
```

**server 2: post method**

```
app.post('/login/callback', function (req, res) {
   // success process..
}
```

Comment: http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect ?

Comment: i dont understand the issue here. do you need help finding the ip/dns of your server2 ? if  not you can just do res.redirect("http://1pof2ndserver/login/callback')

Comment: res.redirect("**/login/callback')  it work only get method. i want to call post method @Rajatbanerjee

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```js
app.get('/sampleTestApp', function (req, res) {

    axios.post(url:'server2/post', data :body={uid:'test'},function(response) {
        res.send(response);
    })
}
```

Comment: What is axios? Is it a separate module.

Comment: oh axios is a library for making api requests from node, but you can use anything. out of the box 'http' or 'request' or axios.